# Zsh - How can I compare a variable whose name begin with '~' symbol against a 'if' statement?

Tags: if-statement, syntax, zsh

I would like to automate zsh's installation and configuration and I am currently unable to check out either a file whose name begin with '~' exists and is not empty.

```sh
zsh_rcfile='~/.zshrc'
set -- $zsh_rcfile
if [ -s "${zsh_rcfile}" ]; then
    printf "Zsh is already configured."
fi
```

When I execute the script into the terminal, no error is returned but no output is produced as well.
I tried to hard code the pathname, or use it without the curly braces but the result is the same.
I also tried not using the `set` command (which prevent nasty surprises with empty names or names beginning with a dash).

The 'if' statement would work without the tilde symbol (*i.e.* ~) but it would account for an inferior solution as I need to automate other processes required to cross the system tree (and not just the 'home' partition).

Does anyone accept to help me achieving the comparison against a path beginning with '~'?

N.B.: I'm using zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-debian-linux-gnu).

Comment: The `set` command doesn't do anything useful; you aren't examining any positional parameters in the following code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tilde expansion isn't performed on the result of a parameter expansion. You want to leave the `~` unquoted so that it *is* expanded when you *define* the parameter.

```
% zsh_rcfile='~/.zshrc'
% print $zsh_rcfile
~/.zshrc
% zsh_rcfile=~/.zshrc
% print $zsh_rcfile
/Users/<user>/.zshrc
```

The `-s` operator returns false if the file doesn't exist in the first place (which makes sense, since a nonexistent file is trivially empty).

```
 -s file
              true if file exists and has size greater than zero.
```